# Why does W3 validation require populated alt and src attribute for images?

Tags: javascript, image

I don't use these properties as I add the src dynamically later.  I don't need alt either.
I do want my page to validate however. I can bypass this requirement by using CSS backgrounds inside a div.  Is this a valid approach?

**Clarification:**

- I don't care about search engines.
- My images always load.
- I set the src attribute using JavaScript.
- For major modern browsers.
- Accessibility not needed yet.
- Doctype is HTML 5 - `<!DOCTYPE html>`

**Reference**

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: If you want your pages to validate write valid code instead of hacks. Also a bit hard to see what you are trying to do, but adding empty `img` tags seems like a wrong approach either way.

Comment: It is better for search engines to have the 'alt' attribute filled in, and if the image for some reason does not load, the user will at least get a description of what the image is supposed to be.

Comment: "Accessibility not needed yet."? Maybe not for you.

Comment: @Stephen It is also how screen readers tell people who use them about the image.

Comment: @thatidiotguy Oh neat! I did not know that. Makes good sense.

Comment: A thoughtful take on this attribute: http://alistapart.com/blog/post/on-alt-text

Comment: Why don't you set them to blank? <img src="/" alt="" /> ?

Comment: Given that it seems like your site (or at least this page) relies heavily on post-page-load alterations with JS, why do you care about the page validating in it's pre-altered form in the first place?

Comment: @AD7six I think he's just trying to get it through validation, he says he's changing it later, I pictured that as something that happens at load, but could be wrong, perhaps we'd need clarification.

Comment: @RandomUs1r "on load" is the only thing that matters to the w3 validator because it's _only_ going to validate the html as served in the initial request - it doesn't process any js that comes with it. It's a valid url so it will validate (except for the empty alt attribute value) - but it generates a request to the server in the process. If you wanted to do that sort of thing you could use a datauri - or point at e.g. /favicon.ico (or any other existing image) - which the browser will have requested already anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Because it's validating to a specification

Html has a specific structure which is documented on the [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/) site. The w3 validator validates that the input matches the specification, in this case matching the requirements:

#### [img tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element)

> The src attribute must be present

An img tag with no src has undefined behavior and, for example, may re-request the current page in lieu of a valid image depending on the browser.

#### [alt attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/embedded-content-0.html#alt)

> the alt attribute must be specified and its value must not be empty

From the same reference, justification for the alt attribute requirement:

> [the alt attribute] is supposed to contain replacement text that could be used by users instead of the image

### Why serve invalid markup

From the question:

> I don't use these properties as I add the src dynamically later. I don't need alt either.

If you're adding the src dynamically (which also implies that without javascript the page, or at least this particular bit of markup, is of no use to anybody) - why not add the img tag dynamically.

Comment: ....I get overwhelmed with options....put it in the CSS as a background property .... add the img tag dynamically all together...all are valid... none presents itself as better than the other ... so I get confused.

Comment: If you're app is heavily js dependent - do it all with js.

Comment: Done.  That is smart.  I will add it dynamically to a holding div.

Comment: begging for upvotes isn't appropriate - they aren't a reward for accepting/voting on answers, they are an indicator of asking a clear and well-researched question. I checked your history and found some worthy Qs though :).

Answer (score 2):

Alt tags are insisted upon based at least partially on federal laws in various countries, as in some contexts and situations it is considered illegal discrimination against disabled persons that can be punished with some very hefty fines - thus, the W3 standards wisely insist upon it if the page is to be considered standards compliant.

Beyond disabilities, alt tags are used in a variety of contexts such as screen readers, when browsers have images turned off, etc.

If you really want to avoid defining alt tags, use a default one, like alt="Alt tag intentionally left blank due to 'reasons'" or somesuch.

As to the source attribute, it goes to the fact that an html page must be internally valid BEFORE scripts are run to be considered standards compliant. This is due to the complexity and unreliability of checking standards compliance after scripts have run, as well as the fact that the standard has been influenced by the idea of "unobtrusive scripting" - where the page can be enhanced by scripts, but it should not insist on scripting for basic functionality when not strictly necessary.

Now if you have a really good reason that your images must be defined at run time, you have two choices:

1. Use a blank or placeholder image, such as a 1x1 transparent gif/png at least.
2. Remove the images from the HTML entirely and add them at run time, instead of just changing the related src attributes.

As to the src tag, one must also remember that as your application grows the loading time will increase, and things might start looking really weird depending on styles and dimensions, etc.

In summary, always use Alt tags even if you think you don't need them, and use one of the two above solutions regarding the src tag.

Comment: +1 for `the page can be enhanced by scripts, but it should not insist on scripting for basic functionality`.

Answer (score 2):

The `alt` attribute is useful for text-based browsers, disability accessibility like screen readers, and search engines (some of which are mentioned in comments on your question).

You probably shouldn't have empty image tags lying around, too. This is semantically wrong (not to mention it fails validation as you have said), and can cause [technical issues](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/) with your site. Instead, perhaps have empty "image holders" (like `div` or `figure`) lying around, and populate their inner HTML content with your dynamic image tags.

Setting the `src` with JS (or even statically) cannot guarantee loading of images. What if the network has a really bad hiccup? You cannot guarantee that all resources will load properly. Dealing with badly loaded JS or CSS can get a bit ridiculous and can be beyond your control, but something as simple as an `alt` tag on your images can be a pretty easy workaround.

Just because you don't need all of these features doesn't mean the W3C shouldn't take them into consideration when making a generalized spec for the *entire world* to follow.